# ipython notebook 11 times slower than python: why?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am running a script in ipython notebook (with Chrome) and noticed that it's 11 times slower than it is if I run the very same script in Python, using spyder as my IDE.
The script is quite simple: it's just a set of loops and calculations on a pandas dataframe. No output is printed to the screen nor written to external files. I expect the code to be slowish because it's not vectorised, I appreciate Ipython may involve some overhead, but 11 times... ! Can you think of any reasons why? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you timing it in both cases?

Comment: I'm timing it with : impor time / start_time = time.time() / elapsed = time.time() - start_time

Comment: And are the timings reproducible if you run it several times in both? IPython is really just running your code in Python internally, so the speed shouldn't be any different.

Comment: Yes, I tried a gazillion times and the timings are the same

Comment: Is it definitely the same Python interpreter running both? Look at `sys.executable` to check? And you definitely have the exact same data? Sorry if these sound like stupid questions, but I really can't think why code would run differently in IPython.

Comment: Yes, same sys.executable in both cases. The code is a (very unoptimised) loop that iterates over certain items of a pandas dataframe to do some calculations. I could optimise it by calculating some fields with pandas.merge, like a sql join, and maybe using Numba, but that's not the point: why Ipython is so much slower is beyond me

Comment: Is the code something you can share so we can try to reproduce it? Or can you produce a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: It's probably chrome

Comment: I've noticed for the past year that python 3 code on any version of Jupyter running from Anaconda Navigator in firefox, will take over 5 secs for a simple print("Hello World")

Answer (score 4):

I tested this on my machine, and found that ipython was actually faster.

```
$ cat ex.py 
import time
import numpy as np
now = time.time() #(seconds)
a = []
for j in range(2):
  for s in range(10):
    a.append(np.random.random())
then = now
print(time.time() - then)

$ python ex.py 
0.142902851105

In [1]: %run ex.py
0.06136202812194824
```

I bet it's the Chrome part of your ipython setup which is causing the slowdown.